# NHibernate one-to-many multiple columns

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having trouble mapping this... is it even possible?

Here is an example:

```
public class Location{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public float Latitude {get;set;}
    public float Longitude {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Weather> Weather {get;set;}
}

public class Weather{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public float Latitude {get;set;}
    public float Longitude {get;set;}
    public DateTime TimeMeasured {get;set;}
    public float Temperature {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

So I would like to have a relation between `Location` and `Weather` entities. They could be joined by `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties, but I don't know how to map this.

This is what I have tried:

```
<class table="locations" name="Model.Location, Model">
...
<set name="Weather" lazy="extra">
  <key>
    <column name="Latitude" />
    <column name="Longitude" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Model.Weather, Model" />
</set>
...
</class>
```

It throws a:

`Foreign key (FK911522E81A761796:weather [Latitude, Longitude])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (locations [ID])`:

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this article on [NHibernate Mappings for Composite Keys with Associations](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/419780/NHibernate-Mappings-for-Composite-Keys-with-Associ) could help you? It looks like you need to define the composite key:

```
  <class name="Product" table="Products" lazy="true" >
    <composite-id name="ProductIdentifier" class="ProductIdentifier">
      <key-property name="StoreID" column="StoreID" />
      <key-property name="ProductID" column="ProductID" />
    </composite-id>
    <set name="Orders" inverse="true">
      <key>
        <column name="StoreID"/>
        <column name="ProductID"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="Order"/>
    </set>
  </class>
```

Comment: Ok. But can I define a composite key without it being primary? Because weather table is unique only by Latitude, Longitude and TimeMeasured. Latitude and Longitude alone are not enough

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's possible. But wouldn't it make more sense to have a FK_Location_ID in your Weather table, thus avoiding the duplication of Latitude and Longitude? Makes your mappings much simpler too.

Comment: No, because there are many locations with same coordinates. It is already a huge table, that would multiply it 10 times at least